# LUA Rounding number to 1

Tags: lua, rounding

I'm assuming there's a better way to do this other than writing a bunch of if statements. What I'm trying to do is round the number to the left down to 1. For instance, if a number is 12345.6789, round down to 100000.0000.. If the number is 9999999.9999, round down to 1000000.0000. Also want this to work with decimals, so if a number is 0.00456789, round it down to 0.00100000.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local function weird_rounding(num)
   return 10 ^ math.floor(math.log(num, 10))
end
```